Unable to load Mattermost if I type my-ip-address/mattermost
I've created an EC2 (Ubuntu) instance. I have set it like that I can access from any ip address. I assigned it an Elastic ip so that it never changes.
Then I installed all required software in it by accessing this instance using SSH.
I set port 8065 for Mattermost. I set Mattermost as a service. I don't have DNS so I'm using ip address directly. I also added a configuration file inside sites-available. But the problem is I'm not able to access Mattermost using my-ip-address/mattermost. I'm only able to access it using my-ip-address:8065/mattermost.
Here is the configuration code:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@44.217.27.149
    ServerName 44.217.27.149

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /mattermost http://localhost:8065/
    ProxyPassReverse /mattermost http://localhost:8065/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mattermost_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mattermost_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

{
    "ServiceSettings": {
        "SiteURL": "http://44.217.27.149/mattermost",
        "WebsocketURL": "",
        "LicenseFileLocation": "",
        "ListenAddress": ":8065",

Please tell me how can I achieve my desired functionality?
